# Do I need to declare the Rental Income from property in India while filing US Federal Tax?

Tags: united-states, india, income, rent, dtaa

Say I own a couple of units in an apartment complex in India and they were
purchased in part by using inheritance (property) and in part by cash 
(funds from US).

If the units are currently rented out and the annual income from renting is
Indian Rupees 150,000 per annum (equivalent to about $3000), do I need to 
declare this rental income while filing US Federal Taxes (as a US citizen)?

Thanks in advance.

Happy Gnome

Answer (score 8):

Yes, you do. As a US citizen, you're required to declare and pay taxes on all of your income, regardless of what country the property is located in.

Comment: Thanks!  Do you have IRS references (like a web page) for more information?  For example, how/where do I declare the additional income?

Comment: @HappyGnome Read the instructions to form 1040, and specifically its Schedule E.